# Service based on observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I got an view that holds 4 components. 
These 4 components subscribes to a service where they get the updated object that they work with.

This is service:

```
@Injectable()
export class testService {

  private testSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Test>(null);

  constructor() { }

  public setTest(test: Test) {
    this.testSubject.next(test);
  }

  public getTest(): Observable<Test> {
    return this.testSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

And the components subscribe as following:

```
this.testService.getTest()
  .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
  .subscribe(
    res => {

      this._test = res;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

The problem is that when I change any property of _test in any component I get a change in the other components as well.
I would like the behavior to be that the change is capsulated in that component and by calling the setTest on the testService I trigger the subscribe in the other components in thier view. Because now it seems they all edit the same object as the service returns a reference.

How can I achive this behavior/pattern easiest? 
Should I deepclone every response from the service in the components?

Br

Comment: Provide your servce at component level.. so that every component have a new instnce of the sevice.

Comment: But the data in testService should be shared between the components. New instances gives new objects for each and no sync between them

Answer (score 1):

Of course. This behavior is because your are using a subject that is hot and all subscribers are notified when it changes. This is the Subject nature.

If you want affect only a component you have two solutions: 
1) use on observable instead of a subject
2) or create one service per component (using @component.providers property), but this is a very bad practice.

Comment: the problem is that you cannot push values to an observable, and is what you need.

Comment: I think your solution is wrong because you are using a hot observable and want to notify only a concrete component.

Comment: I want to notify all 4, if one of them has changed any data in the shared service.

Comment: I will read a bit more, Im sure u are right in the end. Just that I dont understand why. :)

Comment: why do you need and 'state' in a service?
Pushing a value is like to keep an state alive. and this should be managed in a 'model'

Comment: Backend returns one big object. I present it in a view with 4 components that has dependencies to eachother. Like if I check a box in one, show field in a second. So I wanted a service to hold the data and tell every one when its changed and the others should update. Dualbinding was not an option.